# php create new dir with 777 permission. How?

Tags: php, linux, file-upload, file-permissions, 777

In my code

```
$path = 'images/product/'.$pid;
if( ! file_exists($path)) {
    mkdir($path, 0777);
}
...
...
```

but when I type

```
ls -l
```

in terminal

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data 4.0K 2011-12-10 19:28 1/
```

This is the permission that I get, but is not I want.

I want to allow web user to upload the project based on the product ID (directory) that created during runtime.

How can I do so?

Comment: Do you really need 777? *Really*? It is far better to apply ownership by users and groups to allow other users/groups on the box to write to that directory. If you're using 777 so Apache can write to the directory then there's no need, it is already owned by `www-data` and anyone uploading a file via PHP/Apache will have write permissions already.

Comment: I think is not necessary need 777. Thanks for advise.

Answer (score 4):

For creating directories with 777 permissions,or any permissions

```
$path = 'images/product/'.$pid;
if( ! file_exists($path)) {
    $mask=umask(0);
    mkdir($path, 0777);
    umask($mask);
}
```

...

Answer (score 1):

This is because by default the Apache umask is set to 0022 by default.

Since umask is to revoke permission. Example

```
default 0777 rwx.rwx.rwx 
umask   0022 ---.-w-.-w-
Final   0755 rwx.r-x.r-x
```

There are 2 ways to solve this,

```
1. Edit /etc/apache2/envvars
   add in **umask** *<permission to be revoke>*
   restart apache
2. add in umask(0000); before the mkdir('mydir', 0777);
```